# Returning nil in codewars but not in my IDE?

Tags: ruby

I'm running this code on my IDE on my computer and I get the desired results but when I run it with codewars it returns nil.

```
def accum(s)
  s = s.split("")
  counter = 1
  multiplier = 1
  print s[0].capitalize
  loop do
    print "-#{s[counter].capitalize}#{s[counter].downcase * multiplier}"
    counter += 1
    multiplier += 1
    break if counter == s.length
  end
end
```

Can anyone please tell where I'm going wrong?

https://www.codewars.com/kata/5667e8f4e3f572a8f2000039/train/ruby

Comment: You're not returning anything. You're only printing them.

Comment: when you omit a return statement, the return value of the last action is returned by the method. So that is not the string that you print.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code always returns `nil` for me, and reading it, I cannot see any way how it could return anything other than `nil`. If the code in your IDE does not return `nil`, then it is different from the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Change it into

```
def accum(s)
  s = s.split("")
  counter = 1
  multiplier = 1
  out = s[0].capitalize
  loop do
    out << "-#{s[counter].capitalize}#{s[counter].downcase * multiplier}"
    counter += 1
    multiplier += 1
    break if counter == s.length
  end
  out
end
```

where you introduce `out`, append to it in the loop and finally return at the end.

Comment: Given how this is written, it would work just as well to `break out if count == s.length`, as the loop is the last expression in the method.

Answer (score 1):

[Andre Wildberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9462095/andre-wildberg) has already [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75696448/15261315) your problem, which originates from only *printing* and not returning the value you need from your method, but if we think through what you're doing, this can be done in a single expression.

You need to split a string into characters. Let's use `s.chars` rather than s.split("")`. Now you need to loop over them with an index. You also have` multiple`but that and`counter` are always the same value.

To get that index we can use `#each_with_index`. This starts indexes at `0`, so we can just add `1` to get the length of the string.

We can use the enumerator returned by `#each_with_index` to map out the substrings we need and then join them with `"-"`.

```
def accum(s)
  s.chars
   .each_with_index 
   .map { |ch, i| ch.*(i+1).capitalize }
   .join("-")
end
```

Testing this:

```
% ruby
def accum(s)
  s.chars
   .each_with_index 
   .map { |ch, i| ch.*(i+1).capitalize }
   .join("-")
end

puts accum("hello")

H-Ee-Lll-Llll-Ooooo
%
```

Comment: Consider `s.each_char.with_index(1).map { |ch, i| ch.*(i).capitalize }.join("-")`, mainly to avoid creating the array `s.chars`.